# Xcode 6 static library project

Tags: xcode, xcode6, static-libraries, cocoapods, linker-flags

I have a static library project included to my main project.
I followed [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/configuration.html). It worked when I had Xcode 5. It stopped working after I updated to Xcode 6. What might be a reason? I use CocoaPods 0.35.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Cocoapods, you should not set "Other Linker Flags" manually. This is automatically set as part of the **pod install** process.

Part of the Tutorial that you linked to tells you to set the **Other Linker Flags** manually.

Go to your project and clear **Other Linker Flags** value on the project level and the target level (if it is in bold) by highlighting the value and hitting delete.

Once deleted, you should see the inherited value coming from the Pods.xcconfig file. Something like:

```
-ObjC -framework CoreGraphics
```

You can verify this by clicking on "Levels" to the left of the search bar.

This should have you cocoapods libraries sorted. Once this is working add the path to your static library headers by setting `"Header Search Paths"` to `"${inherited} /path/to/static/libary/headers"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this changes nothing. (I do "clean", "pod install", close/open Xcode all the time.)

Comment: Do you have custom xcconfig configured for you project? Do you see any warnings when you run pod install? Post what you are seeing if this is the case.

Comment: after your answer I cleared target's "Header Search Paths" and "Other Linker Flags", and put $(inherited) to both of them. And made "pod install" and all the stuff. But problem is still persist.

Comment: The problem is fixed. But solution wasn't good. I had to add a path to the library headers to "Header Search Paths".

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the answer to include the necessary changes.